# Video Starts Over using SurfaceView when rotating

Tags: android, android-fragments, surfaceview, screen-orientation

When I rotate the screen my video starts over. I am using surfaceview. This is all handled in fragments. I have set android:configChanges="orientation" in my manifest. This is what I have added

```
    <activity
        android:name=".BassActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        >
```

I have also added this in onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (VERBOSE) Log.v(TAG, "+++ onCreate +++");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
```

Nothing seems to change. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Exactly what do you want???

Comment: I want the video to continue playing at the same position when the orientation is changed.Adding the additional configchanges to the manifest worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way

```
<activity
        android:name=".BassActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        >
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
}
```

make sure that my activity goes back to portrait mode if exit this fragment.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); // set the activity back to //whatever it needs to be when going back.
    super.onPause();
}
```

you can also add this to manifest file corresponding to that activity..

```
  <activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    >
```

Comment: Adding the additional configChanges to the manifest for the Activity worked! Thanks